# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium, rsdriver

I'm trying to run RSelenium:

```
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4567L, browser = "chrome")
```

and get the following error

```
Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-3PP62ID', ip: '192.168.89.255', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

When I specify my exact `c`

`rD <- rsDriver(port = 4440L,browser=c("chrome"), chromever="83.0.4103.106")`

I still get an error:

```
version requested doesnt match versions available = 80.0.3987.106,81.0.4044.138,81.0.4044.20,81.0.4044.69,83.0.4103.39,84.0.4147.30
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Upgrade Chrome?

Comment: "Google Chrome is up to date" - presumably this is the last version

Comment: Did you try to replace chrome with firefox?

Comment: I haven't tried - I have a scraping script that was adapted to chrome specifics. Still am looking forward to make it work again :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use exact chrome driver exe accourding your chrome browser version please update your exe file accourding that

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Comment: I did that - I was not able to find my exact version 83.0.4103.106 but downloaded the one that should be generic for 83. It still does not work - when I start the chrome driver it says "only local connections are allowed" and when I run in R it says "starting remote server"... maybe this is the issue

Comment: I also installed the version through command line and now if I check it (chromedriver --version) it says 83.0.4103.39. Still getting the same error from R that "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84". Should I do something in R or in some config file? The following seem available to work with "80.0.3987.106" "81.0.4044.138" "81.0.4044.20"  "81.0.4044.69"  "83.0.4103.39"  "84.0.4147.30" . My version is none of the above - could it be that it's too new?